# How to include and exclude specific values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a few arrays. Each one has 8 values and I want to output a new version of each array with 5 values.

oldArray1 = [**1**,**2**,4,6,12,14,**3**,13]

oldArray2 = [99,**1**,32,12,**2**,**3**,***218***,11]

So the above is an example of two arrays I may have. I want every new array to contain the numbers 1,2 and 3 but to exclude the number 218.

newArray1 = [**1**,**2**,4,12,**3**]

newArray2 = [99,**1**,**2**,**3**,21] .. Something like this.

The only way I can think about is using an "if" statement, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

Comment: You have to use a `for` loop, inspect each element and exclude the ones you don't want using an `if` inside the for loop.  First you might have to count the elements you want to exclude to determine the size of the new array.  In the future, please at least attempt some code when posting.  If you don't know how to start at all please ask your teacher, you should know how to at least get started or your teacher isn't doing something correctly and they need to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the  `Bitmap` idea

So now I know that you need to include 1, 2, 3 in the array, and exclude 218

Now we construct a byte array, this will be the contrast array you need as

like this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[512]; // init byte array, all elements was '0'
// set contains elements ：value = 1 , exclude elements ：value = 2
b[1] = 1;
b[2] = 1;
b[218] = 2;
// todo: loop your array 
for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    // Check element with index like b[oldArray[i]] = 1/0/2, And then do your new array operation

}
```

The specific implementation is up to you. This method can solve more than one comparison problem

Comment: Also, I think your question itself has a problem, you should describe it in more detail